# add custom widget to QTableWidget cell

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have custom widget made with qt designer and i want to add it to QTableWidget cell.
But it doesn't work.

Here is the code :

```
int nRows =10;
for(int row = 0; row < nRows;row++;)

{
    QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem();
    CustomWdg* wdg=new CustomWdg( );

    mTableWdg->insertRow( row );
    mTableWdg->setItem(row, 0, item);
    mTableWdg->setCellWidget( row, 0, wdg );

}
```

Comment: The given code looks correct, I would suspect something is wrong with the custom widget itself.

Comment: The custom widget is standard widget made in qt designer, it has two buttons and two labels. I inherits from QWidget. I don't know what could be wrong with that.

Comment: If you use the widget in another context, is it visible and usable?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean ? It doesn't compile ? It crashes ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to add custom widget into table cell you can use QItemDelegate.

Create your own Delegate class and inherit it from QItemDelegate.

```
class MyDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
    public:
    CChoicePathDelegate (QObject *parent = 0);
    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const; //delegate editor (your custom widget)
    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,
    const QModelIndex &index) const; //transfer editor data to model
    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
    const QModelIndex &index) const;
};
```

And then set delegate for Table with this methods on your own.

```
setItemDelegate(QAbstractItemDelegate *)
setItemDelegateForColumn(int, QAbstractItemDelegate *)
setItemDelegateForRow(int, QAbstractItemDelegate *)
```

---

I have tried this code:

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QHBoxLayout *l = new QHBoxLayout();
    l->addWidget((new QPushButton("I`m in cell")));
    l->addWidget((new QLabel("Test label")));

    QWidget *w = new QWidget();

    w->setLayout(l);

    ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(1,1, w);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

and result is:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 7):

Your code is correct, so the only thing that comes to my mind is that you didn't `setColumnCount(1)` before `for` loop. If that's not the case, you could try to set row and column count before that `for` loop instead inserting row by row in loop:

```
int nRows =10;
mTableWdg->setRowCount(nRows);
mTableWdg->setColumnCount(1);
for(int row = 0; row < nRows;row++;)

{
    //QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem();// line one
    CustomWdg* wdg=new CustomWdg( );
    //mTableWdg->setItem(row, 0, item);// line three
    mTableWdg->setCellWidget( row, 0, wdg );

}
```

If you really need `item` ("line one" and "line three") you should set it like this: `QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem("");`, otherwise you don't need those lines, your `CustomWdg` is properly set with `setCellWidget`