# PyQT: Creating custom Widgets for QListView

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to add a custom Widget to the QListView, i read already the SO thread about Delegates. [QListView/QListWidget with custom items and custom item widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948444/qlistview-qlistwidget-with-custom-items-and-custom-item-widgets)

But how is this applied in pyqt? i couldn't find any example. Some articles show how to overwrite the paint function, which will only change the appearance but not add a widget as an item.

Comment: Google "pyqt delegate example", found: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/pyqt4-qitemdelegate-example-with/

Comment: This example is for painting a widget, not for composing widgets.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What's the difference according to you ?

Comment: It's not setting a widget for an element, its just changes how it appears, in the example you provided, it just changes the background color to red. But i would like to add per item, a custom widget, which can contain for example a qpusbutton or another widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setCellWidget() if you can switch to QListWidget or QTableWidget
[add custom widget to QTableWidget cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317585/add-custom-widget-to-qtablewidget-cell)

...or you can just spawn new Widget in a cell rectangle via delegate like I do here:
[delegate that edits bound python object properties](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B60otNVdbWrrcDRmc3Z3S01IaFk/view?usp=sharing)

We used code like this to handle text, number, date, boolean, image, document file, coordinate, list properties etc of our domain objects.

Comment: Thanks for the Source Max, Is there a file missing ? You have the: ObjectDelegate, but it's not used anywhere, i would like to see how you use this within a list/table view.

Comment: I'd attach small sample tomorrow.
Briefly, we used it with custom Q(Table|Tree|List)Widget, but you surely can do it with QTableView

Comment: Thank you very much bro, i will look into those examples, that helps a lot! By the way, i somehow could see your other files on your driver share too, just make sure, no one sees your private stuff!!

Comment: Thank you! 
One always must remember about security in this web stuff, and I forgot:)